# Error when i tried to display images from an umbraco folder

Tags: c#, umbraco7

The issue is encountered when I was trying to fetch some images from a folder,
The issue gets resolved whenever I switch the media to a new folder.

Any help is appreciated.
The code below is used for fetching Umbraco media

```
foreach (var mediaItem in mediasList)
{
    IPublishedContent media = null;
    Udi udiId;

    if (Udi.TryParse(mediaItem, out udiId))
    {
        media = Umbraco.TypedMedia(udiId);
    }
    else
    {
        media = Umbraco.TypedMedia(mediaItem);
    }
    if (media.DocumentTypeAlias == "Folder")
    {
        var childrens = media.Children();   //getting error in this line

        foreach (var image in childrens)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5961cce5-bda8-480f-a765-a3a3360a0174/the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run?forum=csharpgeneral) forum:

> This isn't an error in and of itself, but more of a feature of your debugger. Some properties require code to be executed in order for the property to be read, but if this requires cross-thread interaction, then other threads may have to run as well. The debugger doesn't do this automatically, but certainly can, with your permission. Just click the little evaluate icon and it will run your code and evaluate the property.

Also, you can get the results if you do `var childrens = media.Children().ToList()` for example.